# From Excel textbox to Access table

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to connect my Excel workbook to a table (ScreeningLogsTEST) in MS Access (ScreeningLogDatabase.accdb), and I am getting this error:

> Run-time error '3001': Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

Can you help me figure out why?

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()

 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
 cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
 "Data Source=Q:\TOC Contract Screenings\ScreeningLogDatabase.accdb"
 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open “ScreeningLogsTEST”, ActiveConnection:=cn, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: Have you tried `source:=“ScreeningLogsTEST”`

Comment: I have tried rs.Open Source:="ScreeningLogsTest"

Comment: Your code ran successfully against my database mockup.  The code that you posted has `“` instead of normal double quotes `"` but that will throw a different error.

Comment: Oh my word.. I changed the quotation marks and it worked. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Lol..that's a common problem with coping code from really old posts.